# Regex for thousand separated numbers

Tags: java, regex, string

How can I verify with regex in Java if a number is thousand separated (for example with dot)?

Of course it doesn't have to accept any negative number. I've already Googled all around and so far the best I found was `[1-9]?\.[0-9]*`. However, it's not perfect. For example it accepts `1.000000000` which is not correct.

How can I verify a positive number with a dot thousand separator? For example the number: `1.024.553` or `100.000`

It should accept:

- `123`
- `123.123`
- `0`
- `12.111`

But not:

- `00`
- `kukac`
- `0.111`
- `1...1`
- `1.1`

Comment: What are the test cases? (List of inputs vs expected outputs.)

Comment: This is the input, and I want to check if it's thousand separated.

Comment: The person who voted down this question could expalin why?

Comment: @Slenkra: I'm not the downvoter, but: You haven't showed any effort to solve the problem yourself. What you posted is not a specific question, it's a code request.

Comment: Well I've tried many regexes, but none of them worked, and I didn't want to copy those dummy tries :) But next time I will take care of it.

Comment: @Slenkra When posting a question on SO, it's important to show what you've tried. If your pattern didn't work or didn't even compile, at least it demonstrates that you tried *something*. Also, for regular expressions, it's critical to state *very clearly* what inputs you want to match. e.g. it's not clear here if you want to also match `1234` or `1,234`, or `0.001`--all of which my pattern will match, though it certainly not clear from your question if you're looking for one will match those inputs.

Comment: @Slenkra FWIW, if you take the time to improve this question, you may have some of the down-votes reversed.

Comment: I improved the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this pattern:

```
^\d+|\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*$
```

This will match any simple sequence of digits without thousands separators, or any sequence with `.` separators between every 3 digits. If you also want to support a comma as a thousands separator, use this:

```
^\d+|\d{1,3}(?:[,.]\d{3})*$
```

Of course, to use any of these in Java, you'll need to escape the `\` characters:

```
String pattern = "^\\d+|\\d{1,3}(?:\\.\\d{3})*$";
```

---

**Update** Given your updated specs, I'd recommend this pattern:

```
^(?:0|[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(?:\.[0-9]{3})*)$
```

You can test it here: [Regex Tester](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%28%3F%3A0%7C%5B1-9%5D%5B0-9%5D%7B0%2C2%7D%28%3F%3A%5C.%5B0-9%5D%7B3%7D%29%2a%29%24&input=123%0A123.123%0A0%0A12.111%0A%0A00%0Akukac%0A0.111%0A1...1%0A1.1)

Comment: It won't match `123.456` which seems valid to me :)

Comment: I modified your regex a bit. Now it can verify a number so it accepts thousand separated by a dot, positive numbers,a single zero, but doesn't accepts numbers starting by zero,negative numbers or bad thousand separated numbers. And of course it doesn't accepts alphabetics.
Accepts:
123 ;
123.123 ;
0 ;
12.111
Not accepts:
00 ;
kukac ;
0.111 ;
1...1 ;
1.1
The modified regex: `"[1-9]+[0-9]*|(?!^0)\\d{1,3}(?:\\.\\d{3})*$|^0"`

Comment: @p.s.w.g I tried your updated regex, and it also worked like charm. Could you explain why you recommend your new pattern and not my modified one?

Comment: @Slenkra To match your latest specifications. Even the one you specified in your previous comment allows some numbers which you said it should not accept.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Well it looks like the regex tester says my pattern isn't correct, but in the example project where I tested it, worked perfectly. That's why I asked for you explanation.

Comment: @Slenkra For one thing, the pattern from your previous comment has `...|^0` which means it will match anything which starts with `0`. It will also match anything which *contains* a `1-9` anywhere. I don't know how you were testing the pattern (perhaps there was some other code which was invalidating some strings).

Comment: Yes you are right, sorry I was a bit confused with the regex, I'm a newbie in it : ) Thanks for the answers!

Comment: how can I add support for negative numbers as well?